# Unable to update (dummy change) the data in an JSON placeholder data using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, crud

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Create from "./Create";
import Album from "./Album";
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
function App() {

  const [users, setData] = useState([]);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false)
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
const [userId, setUserId] = useState('')


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const onAdd = async (title, userId) => {
    const url =  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/"

    await fetch(url, {
      method:users.id ? "PUT": "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: title,
        userId: userId,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status !== 201) {
          return;
        } else {
          return res.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData((users) => [...users, data]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };


  const onUpdate =async({ id,title, userId})=>{

    
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "title",
        userId: "userId",
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json));
  }



  const onDelete = async (id) => {
    await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          return;
        } else {
          setData(
            users.filter((item) => {
             return item.id !== id;
            })
          );
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  console.log(users);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>React Crud Using Jsonplaceholder</h3>
      <br />
      <Create onAdd={onAdd} />
        <h3>There are total {users.length} albums </h3>
          
       <div>
        {users.map((item) => (
          
          <Album
            id={item.id}
            key={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            userId={item.userId}
            users={users}
            onDelete={onDelete}  
            onUpdate={onUpdate}
          />         

        )
      )}
      </div>
      

     
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Update.js

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
export default function Update({id, userId, title, users}){   

  const onUpdate =async({ id,title, userId})=>{

    
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "title",
        userId: "userId",
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json));
  }


  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onUpdate(id, e.target.title.value, e.target.userId.value);
    console.log(id, title, userId)
    e.target.title.value = "";
    e.target.userId.value = "";
}

  const handle=(e)=>{
      const data={...users}
      data[e.target.id] = e.target.value
      console.log(e.target.id)
  }



    return(
        <div>
        <form>
          <h3>Update Album</h3>
          <input  name="userId"               
                  type="number" 
                  placeholder="userId"
                  onChange={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)} 
                  />
          
          <input  name="title"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="title" 
                  onChange={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)}
                />
          <button onClick={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)} >Update</button>
          <hr />
        </form>
      </div>
        )
}
```

Album.js

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Update from './Update'

export default function Album({id, title, userId, onDelete, handleOnSubmit, onUpdate, users }){
    const handleDelete = () => {
        onDelete(id);
    }

    const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false)


    return (
        <div className="albumArt">

            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <p>{userId}</p>
            <span>
                <button onClick={()=>setUpdate(!update)}>edit</button>
                <button onClick={handleDelete} >delete</button>
            </span>
            
        {update && <Update id={id} title={title} userId={userId} users={users}/>}


        </div>
    )
    
}
```

Create.js

```
export default function Create({onAdd}){
   
   
const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onAdd(e.target.title.value,e.target.userId.value);
    e.target.title.value = "";
    e.target.userId.value = "";
}
    return(
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
          <h3>Add Album</h3>
          <input placeholder="title" name="title" />
          <input placeholder="userId" name="userId" />
          <button onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>Add</button>
          <hr />
        </form>
      </div>
        
    )
}
```

I am expecting to update the data in json placeholder api for an instance. I used react hooks to set the values to objects in api and used fetch PUT method to update the data. And unable to pass on the react hooks to next components. Like the state components are not able alter the value of state variables.

Please help in updating the data in this context

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain your issues in details like in which component you got the data and where you need to update it

Comment: I got the issue in updating the data using Update.js. As i used fetch api to update the data. But failing to do so.